# Oracle 12g Importing Cognos XML Data

Tags: xml, oracle

I have simple task to do. 
1) I have Cognos generating report in XML that looks something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataset  xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<!--
<dataset xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:schemaLocation="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/ xmldata.xsd">
-->
<metadata>
      <item name="OID" type="xs:string" length="32"/>
      <item name="NAME" type="xs:string" length="522"/>
      <item name="TYPE" type="xs:string" length="32"/>
      <item name="O_STATUS" type="xs:string" length="52"/>
      <item name="O_REGION" type="xs:string" length="52"/>
      <item name="O_DEV_IN_COUNTRY" type="xs:string" length="12"/>
      <item name="O_START" type="xs:date"/>
      <item name="O_REQ_IMPL" type="xs:date"/>
      <item name="O_B_INIT_APPR" type="xs:string" length="50"/>
      <item name="O_B_FIN_APPR" type="xs:date"/>
      <item name="O_REL_Y" type="xs:string" length="12"/>
      <item name="O_REL_M" type="xs:string" length="12"/>
      <item name="O_REL_T" type="xs:string" length="4"/>
      <item name="O_SIZING" type="xs:date"/>
      <item name="O_BPM" type="xs:string" length="592"/>
      <item name="O_BS" type="xs:string" length="22"/>
      <item name="O_MAINT_ASSESSOR" type="xs:string" length="22"/>
      <item name="O_P_ASSIGN_MGR" type="xs:string" length="32"/>
      <item name="O_FUNC_AREA" type="xs:string" length="102"/>
      <item name="O_APS" type="xs:string" length="22"/>
      <item name="O_INV_TYPE" type="xs:string" length="32"/>
      <item name="O_INV_CAT" type="xs:string" length="92"/>
      <item name="O_INV_SUB_CAT" type="xs:string" length="82"/>
      <item name="O_PRIM_AREA_OF_IMPACT" type="xs:string" length="92"/>
      <item name="O_MAND_REQ_TYP" type="xs:string" length="72"/>
      <item name="O_M_COUNTRY" type="xs:string" length="42"/>
      <item name="O_IMP_COUN_1" type="xs:string" length="42"/>
      <item name="O_IMP_COUN_2" type="xs:string" length="42"/>
      <item name="O_IMP_COUN_3" type="xs:string" length="42"/>
      <item name="O_IMP_COUN_4" type="xs:string" length="42"/>
      <item name="O_IMP_COUN_5" type="xs:string" length="42"/>
      <item name="O_IMP_COUN_6" type="xs:string" length="42"/>
      <item name="O_IMP_COUN_7" type="xs:string" length="42"/>
      <item name="O_IMP_COUN_8" type="xs:string" length="32"/>
      <item name="O_IMP_COUN_9" type="xs:string" length="42"/>
      <item name="O_IMP_COUN_10" type="xs:string" length="32"/>
</metadata>
<data>
    <row>
        <value>X-1234567</value>
        <value>SOME TEXT</value>
        <value>Project</value>
        <value>New</value>
        <value>AAAA</value>
        <value>Yes</value>
        <value>2015-01-01</value>
        <value>2015-02-01</value>
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value>AA12345</value>
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value>SOME TEXT</value>
        <value>SOME TEXT</value>
        <value>SOME TEXT</value>
        <value>SOME TEXT</value>
        <value>SOME TEXT</value>
        <value>SOME TEXT</value>
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value>SOME TEXT</value>
        <value>SOME TEXT</value>
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value xs:nil="true" />
        <value xs:nil="true" />
    </row>
    <row>
    ...
    </row>
</data>
</dataset>
```

2) Such file is send to file share that is mapped as Oracle Directory called IMPDIR

3) I have access to this file from SQL

What I would like to do is to import data from this file in to a table that would have table with fields like in metadata and records would be filled by data from  nodes.

I have search thru Stack and Goolgle and most cases that I have found are related to XML that have clear path with fields that can be distinguish by path.

Any idea how to part such file ? 
The file it self is something around 10MB.

Comment: Does the table already exist, and have the column names you want in the order that matches the metadata? Is it always the same number of columns? Or is it supposed to be entirely dynamic - in which case are you trying to create the table at the same time. or just have a result set?

Comment: Hi Alex. Table exists and have numer and names of columns as in metadata part in xml. What I wnt to do is only import part that is in <data>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic approach is to use dynamic SQL as the column names are part of the  XML. The query below select the column names and values fro each row and return a insert statement that stores the data.

I assume the XML is in table `TST` in column `xml`

```
WITH colnames AS
  (SELECT  pos,
    column_name
  FROM tst t,
    XMLTable( XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/' ), 'for $i in /dataset/metadata/item               
return $i' passing (t.xml) columns 
   pos FOR ORDINALITY, 
   column_name VARCHAR2(30) path '@name' ) x
  ),
  vals AS
  (SELECT vals ,
          rn
  FROM tst t,
    XMLTable( XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/' ), 'for $i in /dataset/data/row            
return $i' passing (t.xml) columns 
    rn FOR ORDINALITY,
    vals XMLType path 'value' ) x
  ) ,
  vals2 AS
  (SELECT rn,
    pos,
    val
  FROM vals,
    XMLTable( XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/' ), 'for $i in /value             
return $i' passing (vals.vals) columns 
   pos FOR ORDINALITY,
   val VARCHAR2(4000) path 'text()' ) x
  )
SELECT rn,
  'insert into TAB ('
  ||
  (SELECT listagg(column_name,', ') within GROUP (ORDER BY pos) FROM colnames
  )
  ||') values ('
  /* quote and escape the string */
  || listagg(case when val is NULL then 'null' else ''''||replace(val,'''','''''')||'''' end,', ') within GROUP (ORDER BY pos)
  ||');' AS insert_txt
FROM vals2
GROUP BY rn
;
```

One example output - perform all inserts with `execute immediate`

```
INSERT INTO TAB
  (
    OID,
    NAME,
    TYPE,
    O_STATUS,
    O_REGION,
    O_DEV_IN_COUNTRY,
    O_START,
    O_REQ_IMPL,
    O_B_INIT_APPR,
    O_B_FIN_APPR,
    O_REL_Y,
    O_REL_M,
    O_REL_T,
    O_SIZING,
    O_BPM,
    O_BS,
    O_MAINT_ASSESSOR,
    O_P_ASSIGN_MGR,
    O_FUNC_AREA,
    O_APS,
    O_INV_TYPE,
    O_INV_CAT,
    O_INV_SUB_CAT,
    O_PRIM_AREA_OF_IMPACT,
    O_MAND_REQ_TYP,
    O_M_COUNTRY,
    O_IMP_COUN_1,
    O_IMP_COUN_2,
    O_IMP_COUN_3,
    O_IMP_COUN_4,
    O_IMP_COUN_5,
    O_IMP_COUN_6,
    O_IMP_COUN_7,
    O_IMP_COUN_8,
    O_IMP_COUN_9,
    O_IMP_COUN_10
  )
  VALUES
  (
    'X-1234567',
    'SOME TEXT',
    'Project',
    'New',
    'AAAA',
    'Yes',
    '2015-01-01',
    '2015-02-01',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    'AA12345',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    'SOME TEXT',
    'SOME TEXT',
    'SOME TEXT',
    'SOME TEXT',
    'SOME TEXT',
    'SOME TEXT',
    NULL,
    'SOME TEXT',
    'SOME TEXT',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
  );
```

Please not that the dynamic select will *scale better* for a large number of columns, but does not handle possible required *type conversions*, that can be done better in a static select.

Comment: Seems complicated when the metadata is known (why I asked for clarification *8-) The target table exists with columns that match the metadata, so XMLTable with a fixed `columns` clause seems reasonable? If they weren't known you could use the metadata to create a table, then use this. But the values need to at least be quoted; or preferably be treated based on the xs-declared data type, to avoide implicit conversion?

Comment: Correct @Alex, after rereading the Q I realized that the probable *preceding question* leading to my solution would be *how can I get the CREATE TABLE statement from the metadata* stuff. Which is far complicated with all the type mapping etc. BTW as you see I didn't manage to get the element position failing with`position()` `count()` and `index-of()` and fallback to ROWNUM. Any ideas?

Comment: You could use [the `for ordinality` option](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB5102); e.g. `... columns pos for ordinality, column_name varchar2...`. and the same for `rn`. I also originally thought the question was looking for a completely dynamic answer, which is slightly more interesting really *8-)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said how you have access to the file - as an external table, something you can read with `utl_file`, or imported into a real table as a CLOB, or something similar. If you can get the entire file into a CLOB then you can get it into an XMLType, or convert it as you go. You then need to transform the generic layout into something relational.

This example assumes you have a table called `t42` that has a column called `xml` which is XMLType and contains your file. You can use XMLTable with FLWOR XQuery expressions ([read more in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm)) that transforms each generic 'item' node into one named using the corresponding metadata entry:

```
select x.*
from t42
cross join xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "xs",
    default 'http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/'),
  'for $row in /dataset/data/row
    return element row {
      for $col_num in (1 to count(/dataset/metadata/item))
        return element {/dataset/metadata/item[$col_num]/@name} {
          $row/value[$col_num]/text()
        }
      }'
  passing t42.xml
  columns oid varchar2(32) path '/row/OID',
    o_dev_in_country varchar2(12) path '/row/O_DEV_IN_COUNTRY',
    o_start date path '/row/O_START'
) x;

OID                              O_DEV_IN_COU O_START 
-------------------------------- ------------ ---------
X-1234567                        Yes          01-JAN-15
X-1234568                        No           14-NOV-15
```

I've added a second `row` node to your sample to make the results slightly more useful, and I've just shown three example columns. Since you know the metadata in advance you just need to create more `columns` entries with the appropriate types and paths, either for all the columns or only the ones you're interested in.

The XMLTable first defines the namespaces you used, with one named `"xs"` and the other as default. This lets all the nodes be identified; though you don't really need `"xs"` to extract the data, and it's a built-in one anyway - you just need the default in this case. Then it iterates over each `row` in your data, and constructs a new `row` element. Then for each row it counts the number of metadata items, and creates a 'column' element for each, named with the `col_num`th metadate item's `name` attribute, and using the `col_num`th row `item` value.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/758e6a/1).

You can use the result of that to insert into your real table (`insert into ... select x.oid, x.o_start from ...`.

If you're reading the data with `utl_file` then you could do the same thing all in one PL/SQL block, something like:

```
declare
  l_clob clob;
begin
  -- populate l_clob with utl_file

  insert into your_real_table (oid, o_dev_in_country, o_start) -- add more columns
  select oid, o_dev_in_country, o_start -- add more columns
  from xmltable(
    xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "xs",
      default 'http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/'),
    'for $row in /dataset/data/row
      return element row {
        for $col_num in (1 to count(/dataset/metadata/item))
          return element {/dataset/metadata/item[$col_num]/@name} {
            $row/value[$col_num]/text()
          }
        }'
    passing xmltype(l_clob)
    columns oid varchar2(32) path '/row/OID',
      o_dev_in_country varchar2(12) path '/row/O_DEV_IN_COUNTRY',
      o_start date path '/row/O_START'
      -- add more columns...
  ) x;
end;
/
```

This gets the file into a CLOB (how to do that is off-topic but sounds like you already have that part covered?), and passes that CLOB straight into the XMLTable expression, converting it on the way with `XMLType()`.

You could possibly also do a XLST transform but that isn't something I've dabbled with much.

---

You don't need a completely dynamic solution, but just for fun, you could build a query dynamically by extracting the `columns` clause members from the metadata, and executing that with the same basic transformation shown above. You could even take it further and create the table dynamically - not something I'd generally recommend at runtime of course, but as I said, just for fun...

```
declare
  l_clob clob;
  l_sql varchar2(32767);
begin
  -- populate l_clob with utl_file

  -- dynamic create table statement from metadata
  l_sql := 'create table t42 (';
  for col in (
    select *
    from xmltable(
      xmlnamespaces(default 'http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/'),
      '/dataset/metadata/item'
      passing xmltype(l_clob)
      columns position for ordinality,
        column_name varchar2(30) path '@name',
        data_type varchar2(30) path '@type',
        data_length varchar2(30) path '@length'
    ) x) loop
      l_sql := l_sql || case when col.position > 1 then ', ' end
        || col.column_name
        || ' ' || case col.data_type
          when 'xs:string' then 'varchar2'
          when 'xs:date' then 'date'
          -- add any other data types used
          end
        || case when col.data_type = 'xs:string'
          then '(' || col.data_length || ')' end;
  end loop;
  l_sql := l_sql || ')';    

  dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
  execute immediate l_sql;

  -- dynamic insert/select creating the `columns` clause from metadata
  l_sql := q'!insert into t42 select *
    from xmltable(
      xmlnamespaces(default 'http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/'),
      'for $row in /dataset/data/row
        return element row {
          for $col_num in (1 to count(/dataset/metadata/item))
            return element column {
              attribute name {/dataset/metadata/item[$col_num]/@name},
              $row/value[$col_num]/text()
            }
          }'
      passing xmltype(:l_clob)
      columns !';
  for col in (
    select *
    from xmltable(
      xmlnamespaces(default 'http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/'),
      '/dataset/metadata/item'
      passing xmltype(l_clob)
      columns position for ordinality,
        column_name varchar2(30) path '@name',
        data_type varchar2(30) path '@type',
        data_length varchar2(30) path '@length'
    ) x) loop
      l_sql := l_sql || case when col.position > 1 then ', ' end
        || col.column_name
        || ' ' || case col.data_type
          when 'xs:string' then 'varchar2'
          when 'xs:date' then 'date'
          -- add any other data types used
          end
        || case when col.data_type = 'xs:string'
          then '(' || col.data_length || ')' end
        || q'! path '//column[@name="!' || col.column_name || q'!"]'!';
  end loop;
  l_sql := l_sql || ')';    

  dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
  execute immediate l_sql using l_clob;
end;
/
```

This will create the `t42` table, and then populate it from the data rows. It's a single insert so more efficient that extracting each data row and inserting those one-by-one.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69c71a/1).

You could also read the column names and data types into a local collection so you don't have to loop over the metadata part twice, which would make it a little more readable and maintainable, but I don't think it would have much effect on performance.

Comment: Nice solution with one XMLTABLE and two for loops! I learned a new approach:)